Marginal Independence despite Confounding
In constructed examples (see below) two variables can have a confounder variable and still be marginally independent. This is commonly regardes to be rare in the real world with complex data generating processes. The so called 'faithfulness' assumptions picks this up and is necessary in causal discovery that a graph can be identified given an (conditional) independence oracle.
Intuitively this makes sense to me, but is there a way to make this principle more rigorous? How unlikely is it that marginal independence occurs despite confounding?
Example ($X_1 \perp\!\!\!\!\perp X_2$, but associated graph $X_1 \leftarrow Z \rightarrow X_2$): Let $Z, Z_1, Z_2$ independent with Rademacher distribution, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Z = 1) = \mathbb{P}(Z = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Define $X_i = Z_i
    Z$ for $i = 1,2$.
I know my question is stated quite broadly. I am interested in broad answers as well as answers in specific subdomains. Actually anything that backs this common believe.

I got a foot in the door with this paper: Geometry of the faithfulness assumption in causal inference (author={Uhler, Caroline and Raskutti, Garvesh and Bühlmann, Peter and Yu, Bin}).
I reference loosely: They mention that the set of unfaithful distributions w.r.t. to a graph has measure zero. It get's more tricky in the actual real world when independence testing is not an oracle, but statistical hypothesis testing with its errors. Then strong faithfulness is defined. This stronger assumption is not as undisputed as the basic assumption. I leave it here to the interested reader to engage further :)
